# Descriptions for posts created by Community user can't be translated

Tags: bug, status-review, revisions-list, localization, community-user

The Community user is officially credited with the creation of empty wikis and excerpts for new tags. The descriptions of these events on Community's activity page always take the form of:

> created *${tag}* (description | excerpt)

Unfortunately, these descriptions are always in English, [even on non-English language sites](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/?tab=activity&sort=posts):

> [image: All Posts tab of Community user's Activity page on ru.SO]

Can entries for these strings be created in Transifex, so we can localize them properly?

Seems related: [The Transifex strings “X wiki description” and “X tag wiki excerpt” are not being used](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317938/339911)