# The Transifex strings “X wiki description” and “X tag wiki excerpt” are not being used

Tags: bug, status-review, tag-wiki, localization, transifex

In Stack Overflow en español we can see [user profiles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/103954/javier-enciso?tab=activity) with this content:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

As seen, it shows:

> ntlk **wiki description**

and

> ntlk **tag wiki excerpt**

Looking at [traducir.win we find the string](https://traducir.win/filters?key=a01f1a122fc46a6dba3c317ad91266a2) translated as

```
$WikiTagName$ extracto de wiki de etiqueta
```

However, the text shows in English.

Could we have this text fixed so it really uses the content in Transifex?

<sub>Initially [reported in Meta SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3721/83) but requested to post in Meta SE.</sub>

Comment: Is this issue still occurring? Looking at [your recent activity on SOes Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/83/fedorqui?tab=activity&sort=all&page=1), it seems like it is. (The user profile your post originally linked to has since been deleted.)